# MySql Group Concat - Don't want rows excluded from Where clause

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Okay, so I have a case where I want to do a Group Concat, but also use the same column that's in the Group Concat as a Where clause further in the statement, but **not exclude** the results in the Group Concat because of the Where. Got it? Hahah here's what I mean:

```
SELECT posts.id, post.post_date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT terms.name ORDER BY terms.name DESC SEPARATOR ';')
FROM posts
INNER JOIN terms on terms.post_id = posts.id
WHERE terms.name = "kittens";
```

So I want to get the posts where the post's terms.name = "kittens", however the post can have multiple terms.name, such as "kittens", "cats", "cuteness", etc etc. So in the Group Concat I want the result to be "kittens;cats;cuteness" (each of these being a separate entry related by posts.id). However with "kittens" in the Where clause, all the Group Concat returns is "kittens".

If I said "WHERE terms.name = 'kittens' OR terms.name = 'cats'", the Group Concat returns "kittens;cats"... but I only want to be searching by one terms.name and get the rest of the terms in the Group Concat.

How can I get around this?

Comment: make the group concat a subquery in the select

Comment: The `GROUP_CONCAT()` function requires a `GROUP BY` clause that is missing in your query. This makes MySQL create a single group from all the selected rows. Because they do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, the values returned for `posts.id` and `post.post_date` are some random values from the corresponding columns.

Comment: @axiac sorry, this is the truncated version of a huge query, just left it out to focus on the point

Answer (score 0):

Use `Having` instead of `Where`. But you also need to include `terms.name` in select clause like this :

```
SELECT posts.id, post.post_date, terms.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT terms.name ORDER BY terms.name DESC SEPARATOR ';')
FROM posts
INNER JOIN terms on terms.post_id = posts.id
HAVING terms.name = "kittens";
```

Comment: This is a step closer, thanks! Results are being omitted for some reason though, I might try find_in_set and check the group_concat itself

Comment: It would work with `HAVING terms.name LIKE '%kittens%'` but this way it is slow like a snail because of (at least) two reasons: 1) the lack of the `WHERE` clause forces MySQL to compute the Cartesian product of the two tables and that could be huge; 2) `LIKE` is slow even for indexed columns, not to mention that here it operates on a computed values (i.e. there is no index involved and no way to optimize it).

Answer (score 0):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name ORDER BY t.name DESC SEPARATOR ';')
FROM posts p
  INNER JOIN terms s ON s.post_id = p.id       # "s" from "search"
  INNER JOIN terms t ON t.post_id = p.id
WHERE s.name = "kittens"                     
GROUP BY p.id
```

#### How it works

If I understand correctly the question, you need to select all the terms of the posts that have the term "kitten". It requires joining the table `terms` twice: once to get all the posts that have the term "kittens" and once again to get the terms of the posts selected this way.

This is what the query does: it joins the table `posts` aliased as "p" ("p" from "post") with table `terms` aliased as "s" ("s" from "search") and selects only the pairs (post, term) where "term" is "kittens". Then it joins the table `terms` again as "t" ("t" from "term") and matches the posts having the term "kittens" with all their terms.

The `GROUP BY` clause creates one group from all the rows having the same `posts.id`. Since `id` is the `PK` of table `posts` there is no need to add `posts.post_date` to the `GROUP BY` clause, `p.post_date` is [functionally dependent on `p.id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're getting at, but unfortunately adding the second join doesn't seem to help...

Comment: I think the issue is that there are multiple joins that are before terms. I think the solution is this case is to be using a better data model XD